# How to call flutter module to android activity in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have successfully integrated `flutter` module in my native android application. but I want to call flutter module to android's module second activity.

for ex. - `Android` module have a two activity, first is MainActivty and other is Second Activity. When user click on MainActivity's screen button `flutter` module open again user click on flutter's module floating button then SecondActivity will be open.

How can I achieve this, please help me.

This is flutter code for go to android :

```
  InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              _showNativeView();
            },
            child:Container(),
          )
```

This is android native class code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

public static final String FLUTTER_TO_ANDROID = "flutterToandroid";


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new FlutterEngine(this));

    // this is for open customer application with staging url
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), FLUTTER_TO_ANDROID).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall methodCall, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {

            if (methodCall.method.equals("showNativeView")) {
                String messagetoflutter = showNativeView();
                result.success(messagetoflutter);
            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }

        }
    });
}

String showNativeView() {

    try {



       Intent i = newIntent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Done, you are Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return "okay";
}

}
```

When showNativeView Method call then it go to SecondActivity.

Comment: please post your relevant code here

Comment: @Quicklearner I have existing android app and i want to open existing app's activity using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create a FlutterMethodChannel then
Invoke method on platform Channel

```
String response = "";

try {
    final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('helloFromNativeCode');
   
 response = result;

  } on PlatformException catch (e) {

    response = "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.";
  }
```